# How to write an update statement for which number of updated columns is dynamic

Tags: plsql, dynamic-sql

I want to write an `UPDATE` statement in which the number of columns may vary for each run, based on the user choice.
Eg: DDL

```
CREATE TABLE "XX_MASK_REF" 
   (    "TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
    "COLUMN_NAME" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
    "FLAG" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR) DEFAULT 'N'
   );
```

A predefined set of table names and the respective column names are inserted into this table. The default value for the FLAG is set to 'N'.The user depends on his requirement will set FLAG to 'Y' which will vary for each run.

Sample data: Run 1

```
Table_Name Column_Name Flag
    T1        C1    Y
    T1        C2    Y
    T1        C3    N
    T2        C1    N
    T2        C2    Y
```

Sample data: Run 2

```
Table_Name Column_Name Flag
  T1           C1   Y
  T1           C2   N
  T1           C3   N
  T2           C1   N
  T2           C2   Y
```

I need an UPDATE statement which should run only for those columns to which the `FLAG` is set to `Y` group by `table_name`. From the dataset given above, In the `Run 1`, the No of columns for table `T1` is `2` whereas in the `Run 2` it is only one column that needs to be updated.

The update statement generated should be able to update all the records available in the table which means where clause is not required.

The values to be updated will be available in variables. I intended to use the TRANSLATE function through which the values will be passed to the column to the column to be updated.

I think something like this would help me

```
V_CHAR := 'Update' ||' ' ||V_TABLE_NAME||' ' || 'Set' ||' ' || V_COLUMN_NAME||'='||' ' || 'TRANSLATE('||V_COLUMN_NAME||', '1234567890','abcdefghijk')
```

Please advise me if i miss anything or unclear

Comment: Where will the update values come from? Where will the filter criteria come from?

Answer (score 0):

As APC commented, your question is incomplete, It does not mention where the update values and the `where` clause for each table comes from.

If you are simply looking for generating update statements without where clauses to run manually after putting appropriate changes, you may use a simple select query like this

```
SELECT
    'UPDATE '
    || table_name
    || ' SET '
    ||
        LISTAGG(column_name
                  || ' = :'
                  || ROWNUM,',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                column_name
        )||';'
    AS v_upd_set
FROM
    xx_mask_ref
WHERE
    flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY
    table_name
```

This will display rows with bind arguments to be used for passing values while running them.

```
UPDATE_QUERY                   
-------------------------------
UPDATE T1 SET C1 = :1,C2 = :2;
UPDATE T2 SET C2 = :3;
```

If you don't want this solution, edit your question and provide us more details.